# MySQL Error with TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE heros (
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
battletag varchar(64) ,
name varchar(32),
id int,
level int,
hardcore bool,
gender bool,
dead bool,
class varchar(32),
updated TIMESTAMP
";
```

Getting an error:

> Error creating table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 11

Comment: It's not a error with a timestamp, it's you lost the `)`

Comment: I have no excuses for myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting your closing `)` character. Cleaned:

```
CREATE TABLE heros (
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    battletag varchar(64) ,
    name varchar(32),
    id int,
    level int,
    hardcore bool,
    gender bool,
    dead bool,
    class varchar(32),
    updated TIMESTAMP
)
```